# How to Transfer Wordpress Website?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, file-transfer

i want to transfer wordpress website from one hosting provider to another. i try also transfer but after transfer i can not change the **Permalink**.i change the **Permalink** from default to Post name. but err shown ...

"404 Not Found"

Comment: Check .htaccess file and compare it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `old-domain` to `new-domain` in guid column in the `wp-post` table in `WordPress database`

And also change the `siteurl` and `home` in wp-option table.

check below link
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updating-links-in-old-posts-when-things-change

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that could be wrong. Usually this error occurs when there is no .htaccess file present, or it's not configured correctly. (Keep in mind: if you new host is not running Apache, then you're not dealing with .htaccess altogether) It might also be that mod_rewrite is not set.

First thing to try though: set your permalinks back to default, or date and save it. Then set it back to pretty permalinks with %postname% and save it. Quite often this actually solves your issue in case the correct accessfile is actually present. :')

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on whether you have changed the domain?
Look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is in your database replacement.

please try this link [Click here](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to download file and relapse your database.

before run this file make backup your database.

**following this step.**

> i)uplode download file in your folder(root folder eg.wp-config.php location).
>
> ii)run this folder.
>
> iii)first run as dry run.if any change is found than run as live.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WordPress plugin called duplicator. Using this plugin we can transfer WordPress website from one host to another. I think this is the simple and easy way to transfer WordPress sit. [Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) is the link.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only way you should ever do it if you at least don't have solid server-side knowledge is using All-in-one WP Migration plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

It allows you to export your database, media files, plugins, and themes. You can apply unlimited find/replace operations on your database and the plugin will also fix any serialization problems that occur during find/replace operations.